# Which recreational math problems could qualify for a Fields Medal during the last 10 years?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Exploring the realm of recreational mathematics, I am intrigued by the notion that problems within this playful domain could serve as a catalyst for significant mathematical development. I am particularly curious to know if any mathematicians have successfully bridged the gap between recreational math and the prestigious Fields Medal. In essence, I am exploring the possibility that seemingly lighthearted puzzles and challenges could inspire mathematicians to delve into profound mathematical explorations, ultimately leading to the recognition of their achievements with one of the highest honors in the field

Comment: John Conway was one of the more formidable mathematicians of my lifetime.  He did not win a fields medal.  However, many of his mathematical contributions began as games.

Comment: Genius truly transcended formal accolades. It's fascinating how his mathematical endeavors often sprouted from playful games. Let's delve into the intriguing world of math-inspired games together—any favorites or recommendations?

Comment: @user317176 Richard Borcherds was Conway's student and did win a Fields Medal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Borcherds - part of the citation related to the Moonshine conjecture which had to do with the Monster group. The serious mathematics here intersects with the study of the Leech Lattice in 24 dimensions: the related Miracle Octad Generator appears in "Winning Ways" (Berlekamp, Conway and Guy) in a recreational context in the analysis of a game called Mogul.

Comment: @MarkBennet That looks like an answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I was not trying to suggest otherwise - it is one of those unique and unexpected mathematical objects which have consequences and relationships all over the place and relates to fascinating delicate exceptions. And although Mogul as a game is completely consonant with the other games being discussed at that point in the book, I suspect it was discovered/noticed as interesting after the MOG. I was lucky enough to attend some of Conway's lectures in the early 1980s and he was always making connections.

Comment: Another Conway link is through his co-authored (and beautiful and brilliant) book "The Symmetries of Things" (John H Conway, Heidi Burgiel and Chaim Goodman-Strauss) in which they bring to life a geometric idea of an "orbifold" that Conway got from Fields Medallist Bill Thurston (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thurston).

Comment: A human readable proof of the four color theorem would do it.

Comment: I took a class with Bill Thurston.  We constructed Platonic solids with children’s toys, measured the curvature of kale, tied knots, and sewed tori.